# Dsum function query access

Tags: vb.net, function, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Hi  am working on query  I tried this Dsum function , would you please correct me this ??

Sum: DSum("Qte";"sales";"[product]![article]=[sales]![article]")

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14aqp.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It could be:

```
Sum: DSum("[Qte]";"[sales]";"[article] = " & [product]![article] & "")
```

If article is text:

```
Sum: DSum("[Qte]";"[sales]";"[article] = '" & [product]![article] & "'")
```